# Show titles, date of all posts on single category page

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, customization

So I am designing a page where I'm showing all the categories like this: [image]

I created a custom page template for this and added this code:

```
                <div class="timeline-post-categories">
                  <?php
                    $categories = get_categories();
                    foreach($categories as $category) {
                       echo '<div class="col-md-4 post-categories"><a href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '">' . $category->name . '</a></div>';
                    }
                  ?>
                </div>
```

and with some css I was able to create the exact replica of this page. 
Now the problem is when I click on any category they take me to the category's single page which shows all the blogs with entire content. My problem is I want to show only the title and date in a similar timeline design view, something like this: [image]

Comment: You need to find out which file its using to show single category page. It could be either `category.php` or `archive.php` it not available then its `index.php`. Once you are sure which file its using then edit it accordingly.